# Does gcm require each device to register using a google account?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to use gcm push notifications. I have gotten my api key.
I understand that gcm requires each device to register before using the gcm service. What i am not clear about is the meaning of registration? Does each device user need to have a google account for the app to work on his device? Or any email address would do?
Any clarification would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be one Google account setup on device.. else the app won't be able to receive gcm push notifications.

Comment: by one google account you mean gmail (most common i'd assume).

Comment: yeah.. anyways an android phone to access play store they need to configure an gmail account... so there won't be an issue

Comment: i was planning to install the app and distribute the phone so no play store needed. but thanks! would have to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

After ICS 4.0.4 GCM does not require a Google Account.

Registration means that you need to register with Google Cloud the device running your application.

Also, after I/O 2013 GCMRegistrar library is deprecated. Applications using it still work but Google encourage developers to use GoogleCloudMessaging. This requires the Google Play Services Library in the device, if it is not, Google Play will attempt to install it. Google Accounts are still not necessary according to Google.

According to some folks out there GoogleCloudMessaging is buggy and does not work properly in certain devices reporting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE when trying to register.